# explanation on some perceptron parameters from scikit-learn

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, perceptron

I need to use the perceptron algorithm to study the learning rate and the asymptotic error of some datasets which are not linearly separable.
In order to do this, I need to understand a few parameters of the constructor. I spent plenty of hours googling them but I still can't understand quite well what they do or how to use them.
The ones that create me more problems are: alpha and eta0

I understand that every update of the algorithm is:

[image: formula perceptron update]

where (d-y(t)) just gives the desired + or -, in order to increase or decrease the component of the vector, and r is the learning rate that smooths the update.

from the scikit-learn documentation (https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.Perceptron.html) 
'alpha' is a constant that multiplies the regularization term if regularization is used.
'eta0' is a constant by which the updates are multiplied.

What is the regularization term (alpha) in the perceptron? in which part of the formula appears? 
Is the eta0 the 'r' of the formula above?
Both of these parameters should slow the algorithm but make it more efficient, I would like to understand how to use them at their best.

Thank you in advance, I will appreciate any answer even if not complete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first let me address this:

> where (d-y(t)) just gives the desired + or -, in order to increase or decrease the component of the vector

to be more precise, (d-y(t)) is the distance between actual output and desired output. it makes sense that our correction should be in proportion to the error size (and it's obtained from a mathematical proof).

> What is the regularization term (alpha) in the perceptron? in which part of the formula appears?

from scikit learn docs on [Perceptron](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.Perceptron.html):

> Perceptron is a classification algorithm which shares the same underlying implementation with SGDClassifier. In fact, Perceptron() is equivalent to SGDClassifier(loss="perceptron", eta0=1, learning_rate="constant", penalty=None).

and on [SGDClassifier](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.SGDClassifier.html):

> The regularizer is a penalty added to the loss function that shrinks model parameters towards the zero vector using either the squared euclidean norm L2 or the absolute norm L1 or a combination of both (Elastic Net). If the parameter update crosses the 0.0 value because of the regularizer, the update is truncated to 0.0 to allow for learning sparse models and achieve online feature selection.

so there you have it. the regularization term keeps model parameters as small as possible. this is also done in neural networks: [here](https://towardsdatascience.com/understanding-the-scaling-of-l%C2%B2-regularization-in-the-context-of-neural-networks-e3d25f8b50db) is a good explanation.

> Is the eta0 the 'r' of the formula above?

yes, learning rate is usually denoted by eta.

Comment: I don't have clear how the regularizer works on the loss function in the update. I thought the loss function was (d-y(t)) and its shape depends on how it is implemented but I imagined something similar to step function that goes from 0  to 1. The further from the goal the bigger the increment of the weight vector. 
I now believe I haven't understood at all.
I'm confused because eta0 and alpha look like are the same parameter to me... what am I missing?

Comment: regularizer adds a term to the loss function to put additional constraints on our results, so for example if your usual loss function is Mean Square Error of output with regularization might be `MSE + |W|` which means the size of weights should also be small (although that does not make much sense in a single Perceptron), the alpha is applied to `|W|` not the weight change. (d- y) is between -1 to 1 for perceptrons and your intuition was correct, I just gave a more precise explanation of where (d-y) comes from. I hope this has made it more clear.

Comment: I get now what changes what, thank you! I still don't understand what all these concerns on the loss function are about, I feel like everything would work with the simple update function mentioned. Is it maybe because I only studied how a single perceptron work?

Comment: I don't know which textbooks or resources your using, so i'm not sure about how much emphasis on loss functions they have put, but generally speaking yes, loss functions become much more important when you have a neural network instead of a single Perceptron.